# How to display error and load the rest of the page if database-related content is optional?

Tags: php, error-handling

My .php includes quote.php followed with the rest of the page.
When the connection fails, I see the following error and the remainder of the page does not load:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: ----- include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') ----

Consider that the DB referenced here is in another classroom and at times their priorities requires them to exclude access. We don't want to be dependent on that.

What must I do to display an error message and then continue to load the rest of my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is a rare case when using a try catch is justified.

All you need to do it wrap the include in a try-catch:

```
try {
    require 'quote.php';
} catch(\Throwable $e) {
    error_log($e); // for the future inspection
    echo "Problem loading this part of page";
}
```

That's all. The error message will be shown and the rest of the page will be loaded.

But of course this approach should only be used when the content from quote.php is optional. In the every other case there must be no local try-catch but a site-wide error handler.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is the same regardless of what functionality is optional on your site. It's not specific to database connection. It could just as well be a website that you want to `curl` and that website is offline.

The technique is called [exception handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). It's very similar in most high-level languages. One part of the code (the optional part) is performing the tasks as usual, and if it cannot perform them, it throws an exception. The core of the application is then responsible for either catching and recovering from the exception or gracefully exiting.

PHP (in the latest versions) throws exceptions by default whenever a DB connection cannot be opened. You don't need to do anything extra there. Wherever you call the optional functionality from, you wrap it in try-catch and recover from it however you wish. For example:

```
try {
    getQuoteFromDB();
} catch(mysqli_sql_exception|PDOException) { // use whichever exception you need, not both
    // Log the error and display different part of the site
}
```

When designing the optional part yourself, if you want to throw the exception, just do:

```
if (/* something cannot be done */) {
    throw new Exception('Something cannot be done');
}
```

It might be a good idea to abstract from the underlying DB extension in your quote.php file by catching the exception and rethrowing a custom one.

Answer (score -3):

php / msqli is throwing exceptions. You need to write exception handler code (`try { } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { }` code in your program to handle errors.

As a quick and sleazy workaroud for the current state of your code you can put this line of code at the top of your page. give this line of code

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF):;
```

This will suppress php exceptions and warnings, and let you rely completely on `mysqli_connect_errno()` to catch your errors.

Comment: Thank you, @O. Jones. Even with ``` mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF); ``` and changing the $Dbname to a non-existing data base as a test, the page did not load.

Answer (score -3):

Using @O. Jones idea and some nasty GoTO's, this does the job. The warnings and error are still displayed. The rest of the page is able to load now.

```
<?php
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
    $dbServer =   "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbName =     "project_01";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServer, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to the MySQL Database: ";
    goto end;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  tbl_quotes";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
        // Return the number of rows in result set
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $rand = random_int(1,$rowcount);
        } else {
            echo "No records were found";
            goto end;
            }
    $sql = "SELECT quote, credit FROM  tbl_quotes where ID = $rand";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        // Fetch one and one row
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
       printf ("%s" . " - " . "(%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
       }
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    end:
?>
```

Thanks to all who looked.